# How to properly add Firebase jar file to libgdx HTML5?

Tags: libgdx, firebase

Firebase jar file works for both iOS and Android. 
But when I try to deploy the web version, it gives me an error:

```
 [ERROR] Line 18: No source code is available for type com.firebase.client.Firebase; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

I tried to add the dependencies in the module settings to the HTML project.

But it still gives me this error.

Does anyone know how to solve this? 
Any advice would be appreciated.